# Cannot retrieve image by relative path

Tags: java, image, swing, path, embedded-resource

I am trying to retrieve a picture by relative path but it always returns a java.lang.NullPointerException no matter what path combination I try

```
private final Icon cardBack = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
    "src/main/resources/Images/cardIcons/cardBack.png"));
```

[image]

https://pastebin.com/sDjP87p3

Comment: Try using `/resources/Images/cardIcons/cardBack.png`. The `src` prefix would not typically make it into the jar. I doubt `main` would either. **Always** use the leading slash with `getResource` - to search from the root of the class path. At least until it first works.

Comment: I've tried every path combination and the problem persists. I am completely stumped.

Comment: 1) Make a copy of the jar. 2) Change the file extension from `.jar` to `.zip`. 3) Open it using a Zip utility. 4) Locate the image. 5) .. get back to me if you can't figure the problem.. -- There are ways to achieve the same using command line SDK tools, but the above might be simpler.

Comment: Try using `/Images/cardIcons/cardBack.png` (with leading `/`, and without the source-folder name in front)

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys! Thomas' solution works in eclipse , while following Andrew's steps , I found the right path and it worked while running the jar. However neither solution worked for both running the jar and running from eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `private final Icon cardBack = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/cardIcons/cardBack.png"));`

Worked after I remade the app into a normal java project. Apparently the problem was caused by Maven, cause yet unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the NPE is being thrown from the `ImageIcon` constructor as `getResource` is returning null.

Try the following:

```
private final Icon cardBack = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("src/main/resources/Images/cardIcons/cardBack.png"));
```

Or:

```
private final Icon cardBack = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("src/main/resources/Images/cardIcons/cardBack.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this error before. You have to add the " / " before your path.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Problem persists.